# How do i put a Windows Form link to download my form onto a HTML webpage

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio, winforms

I was just wondering how I would put a download link of my windows form onto a webpage(I made in Visual Studio). I dont understand how I cant display it in a webpage in the first place, can someone explain?

Thanks

Comment: You don't. You rewrite your application to use web application conventions and frameworks. Assuming you literally wanted someone to run your Win Forms app within their browser. If that's not what you meant, you should clarify your question.

Comment: I hope you mean putting the download link of your application/installer into a page.

Comment: That's simply not possible. Your web app runs in a browser, while the form you are describing is most certainly running natively.

Comment: @Reza Aghaei Yeah but how do I do that?

Comment: @mason How do I rewrite it to use web app conventions and frameworks?

Comment: You learn a web application framework. Which of course is far too broad to ask about.

Answer (score 1):

Using windows forms inside the bowser is not possible, the browser will not understand it, few years ago Silverlight was a promising solution which was not html based but can use some of your desktop skills, but it is not there anymore.
Currently there is a promising project https://blazor.net/ which is:

> Build a Web UI with C# Blazor is an experimental .NET web framework
>   using C# and HTML that runs in the browser.